# Access a local PHP variable is faster that access a session PHP variable?

Tags: php

This is justa a performance question.

What is faster, access a local PHP variable or try to access to session variable?

Comment: -1: the .0000001ms a year you would have saved were lost merely by asking this question. Don't waste time on microoptimizations, and please don't be willing to shove local variables into the session just because you think it gives you an infinitesimal performance edge.

Comment: @juliet: He can't even ask the question out of curiosity?

Comment: @webbiedave Most of PHP developers believe that optimization stands for using "faster" operators. And such "out of curiosity" questions makes it even worst.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I'd like to see a report on that specific stat. Otherwise, it's just empty chatter.

Comment: I wish this site was a bit more professional than enthusiast one...

Answer (score 7):

I do not think that this makes any measurable difference. `$_SESSION` is filled by PHP before your script actually runs, so this is like accessing any other variable.

Answer (score 5):

Superglobals will be slightly slower to access than non-superglobal variables. However, this difference will only be noticeable if you are doing millions of accesses in a script and, even then, such difference doesn't warrant change in your code.

```
$_SESSION['a'] = 1;
$arr['a'] = 1;

$start = 0; $end = 0;

// A
$start = microtime(true);
for ($a=0; $a<1000000; $a++) {
    $arr['a']++; 
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . "<br />\n";

// B
$start = microtime(true);
for ($b=0; $b<1000000; $b++) {  
    $_SESSION['a']++;   
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . "<br />\n";

/* Outputs: 
0.27223491668701
0.40177798271179

0.27622604370117
0.37337398529053

0.3008668422699
0.39706206321716

0.27507615089417
0.40228199958801

0.27182102203369
0.40200400352478
*/
```

Comment: Too bad there's no practical way to bench the session open/close overhead. Unserializing a session might be a bit more expensive than simply loading a .php file with a bunch of variable assignments in it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, are you talking about setting the `$_SESSION` variable to a local variable for use throughout the file or simple talking about the inherent differences between the two types of variables?

One is declared by you and another is core functionality.  It will always be just a smidge slower to set the `$_SESSION` variable to a local variable, but the differenceenter code here is negligible compared to the ease of reading and re-using.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing performance-related in this question.
The only those performance questions are real ones, which have a **profiling report** in it.
Otherwise it's just empty chatter.

Actually such a difference will never be a bottleneck.
And there is no difference at all.

Comment: You can just answer "NO, there is no difference". Thank you for your "common sense"